# ImageMagick Webp identified as VIDEO

Tags: imagemagick

ImageMagick version: **7.1.0-4**

Operating system: **Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS**

Description

Extracted AppImage downloaded from (https://download.imagemagick.org/ImageMagick/download/binaries/magick) identify webp as VIDEO

`./AppRun identify -debug ALL -ping WEBP_500kB.webp`

identify: no decode delegate for this image format `VIDEO' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/572.

- [WEBP_500kB.zip](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/files/7011454/WEBP_500kB.zip)
- [error.log](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/files/7011455/error.log)
- [version.log](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/files/7011508/version.log)
- [delegates.log](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/files/7011509/delegates.log)

Steps to Reproduce

- Download AppImage from => https://download.imagemagick.org/ImageMagick/download/binaries/magick
- Extract AppImage => ./magick --appimage-extract
- Rename squashfs-root folder to => magickdir
- cd magickdir
- ./AppRun identify -debug ALL -ping WEBP_500kB.webp

Comment: Do you have webp installed in ImageMagick?  Does webp get listed in Features when you do `magick -version`?

Comment: @fmw42, Webp is not listed but in the delegate file Its there with dwebp & cwebp commands. Please have a look at the attached files for more information.

`Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-4 Q16 x86_64 2021-07-18 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(4.5)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr png raqm tiff x xml zlib`

Comment: If it is not listed, that means that it was not compiled in a way that ImageMagick knows about it. Perhaps you installed it, but did not recompile Imagemagick to find it. Or perhaps, it was missing some other delegate needed to install webp. Check the config.log file to see if it shows any install errors. If you run `magick -list format` does that list WEBP. If so, what does it say. Does it say rw+? Does it list the libwebp version?

Comment: @fmw42, This is not compiled locally. It's the AppImage downloaded from ImageMagick site for Linux distributions. But my concern is why it is recognizing it as VIDEO instead of WEBP. If you check the error.log file that I've attached you can see that It has identified it as a WEBP and then again identified as a VIDEO. 
`VST* rw-   Truevision Targa image
WBMP* rw-   Wireless Bitmap (level 0) image
WEBM  rw+   Open Web Media
WMV  rw+   Windows Media Video
WPG* r--   Word Perfect Graphics
X* rw+   X Image`

Comment: If webp is not properly installed, Imagemagick might identify it as something else. I do not see WEBP in your list there. Sorry, I do not know what AppImage is? Is that the magick portable. If so, perhaps it is not compiled with webp. Perhaps ask the developers to put webp in it.

Comment: @fmw42, Yes, AppImage I'm referring is magick portable for Linux.

[Linux Binary Release](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

`Complete portable application on Linux, no installation required. Just download and run. AppImages require FUSE and libc to run. Many distributions have a working FUSE setup out-of-the-box. However if it is not working for you, you must install and configure FUSE manually.`

Comment: I do not know much about Appmage portable for Linux. I think you need to refer this to the Imagemagick developers.

Comment: @fmw42, Thanks. I'll open a ticket on GitHub with the developers.